# Setting ttk Notebook tabs in the center [Python]

Tags: python, tkinter

I want to make my own style in a python / tkinter application using ttk Notebooks.  I like the style of the aqua setting shown below.

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk

root = tk.Tk()
s = ttk.Style(root)
s.theme_use('aqua')

notebook = ttk.Notebook(root)
frame1 = ttk.Frame(root, width=400, height=400)
frame2 = ttk.Frame(root)
notebook.add(frame1, text="Frame1")
notebook.add(frame2, text="Frame2")
notebook.pack()

root.geometry("400x400")
root.mainloop()
```

[image: aqua theme]

But aqua will not let me change the background color of some widgets so I want to use the default style.  Is there a way to configure the TNotebook.Tab using the default style to get the tabs in the middle?  Something like

```
s.configure('TNotebook.Tab', tabposition='center')
```

but I have not found anything that works.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I couldn't use theme `aqua` on Windows, but use default theme and

```
s.configure("TNotebook", tabposition='n')
```

could make the tab in the center.

[image]